# Parsing Error using RestKit : Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'application/json'

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

Recently I am facing the following issue,

In my app we perform multiple data sync operation to fetch data from our custom backend,
During this sync process we receive the following error for certain APIs.

**Console log:**

```
restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:172 GET 'https://MY URL GOES HERE' (200 OK / 0 objects) [request=0.5286s mapping=0.0000s total=0.5491s]: 
Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain
Code=-1017 "Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'application/json'"
UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://MY URL GOES HERE,
NSLocalizedDescription=Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'application/json',
NSUnderlyingError=0x170455cf0
{Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unexpected end of file during JSON parse." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unexpected end of file during JSON parse.}}}
```

Issue Behaviour:

- It happens most of the time,
- But sometimes the sync works perfectly,
- Cannot able to predict when this will occur.
- And in the rest kit log the full json data is not getting printed for those particular error APIs, But If I try the same API in Terminal(CURL) full JSON is getting printed, and also tried in HURL.it even there full json is getting printed.

If anyone aware of this issue, please update your answer.

Comment: Did you use Charles, what headers are sent and received, what content size, what's the actual size of the payload?

Comment: @Wain : No, I didn't check using Charles, But I didn't face the issue after some time. I don't know what happened and I didn't even change any code. It worked fine before and now its working fine, just for few hours this issue happened. May I know can this issue occur due to any network issue ?

Comment: sure, if the payload data gets corrupted or truncated...

Comment: Oh, Ok Thank you @Wain